# Bootstrap navbar alignment issues

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In Bootstrap 4 within the toggler hamburger menu is active clicking it will show HomeAbout on the one line, not sure why these aren't on separate lines.

[image: 1]

Code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">    
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Example</a>    
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row ml-md-auto d-md-flex">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="dropdown" to="">About</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Feedback</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/StoogeMate/qts6gamk/

There's no obvious answer I've been able to find through using Bootstrap itself particularly for the first problem without overriding the .css itself and applying !important tags

Does Bootstrap have this capability?

Comment: Please post one question at a time. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts

Comment: Fixed, question only has one question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default, a dropdown menu is automatically positioned 100% from the top and along the left side of its parent. Add .dropdown-menu-right to a .dropdown-menu to right align the dropdown menu.
>
> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment

1. Remove `dropdown` from  the **About** menu  item
2. Wrap  the **About** menu item in a `div.btn-group`
3. Use `dropdown-menu-right` on `div.dropdown-menu`

```
      <li class="nav-item">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="dropdown" to="">About</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Feedback</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
```

Remove `flex-row` to show the menu items on two lines.

```
 <ul class="navbar-nav ml-md-auto d-md-flex">
    ----     
 </ul>
```